# Face Recognition using c++ and opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to compare between two faces using openCV , how can I do that ?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'd suggest adding more to this question, such as what have you tried, and what you are hoping to achieve. You say you want to do facial recognition, but also comparing two images, those aren't really the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing between 2 images can be done by accessing each pixels and taking the difference or use the absolutedifference () to compare the two frames